# Use $wpdb in wordpress theme files

Tags: wpdb

I want to use $wpdb in a theme file, but it doesn't work. My code is bellow:

```
<?php


$action = $_POST['action'];
$updateRecordsArray = $_POST['recordsArray'];


if ($action == "updatelist") {

    $listingCounter = 1;
    $column = $_GET['column'];

    foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $key=>$value) {

    $wpdb->update('wp_postmeta', array('meta_value'=>$column), array('post_id'=>$value, 'meta_key'=>'dbt_text') );
    $wpdb->update('wp_posts', array('menu_order'=>$listingCounter), array('ID'=>$value) );

    $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  

    }
}


?>
```

I think that $wpdb must be declared global or I must include certain files. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Undefined variable: wpdb

Comment: It's probably a scope issue. Is this being included from within a function? Are you initializing Wordpress?

Comment: I don't think so. The code bellow is all that i have in the php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect your script to Wordpress before you can use `$wpdb`.

The usual way to do this is to include `wp-blog-header.php`:

```
 include "/path/to/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there an alternative to /path/to/wordpress/ ? Now my path to wordpress is C://xampp/htdocs/new/ and I don't want to use it that way.

Comment: @zuzuleinen if you're in the same directory with this script, you don't need to use the path. `wp-blog-header.php` alone will do then

Comment: I'm not in the same directory, I am in my theme directory. Should I copy wp-blog-header.php in my theme files or there's a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: @zuzuleinen you can use relative paths, e.g. `../../../wp-blog-header.php` Do not copy the header file, it won't work

Comment: if you want it to work in all cases (you could suddenly decide you want to have subdirectories in your theme etc...), you can also get the wp-header-file like this: get_option('home') . "/wp-blog-header.php"; this will always work.

Comment: @Michiel There is a small problem in your approach. Can you spot it? :)

Comment: not immediately, but feel free to enlighten me ;)

Comment: @Michiel without the `wp-blog-header.php`, there is no WP library present, so no `get_option()` yet. Only after you have the header, can you find out the blog's home directory

Comment: that might be a small problem i overlooked :p thanks for pointing that out ^^

Answer (score 3):

Before you can use wpdb class:

```
global $wpdb;
```

Comment: exactly, you need to call the global wpdb varaible by using global $wpdb;